# Generic parameter types don't narrow when constrained by others

Tags: typescript

My function has a generic parameter `T` and another parameter that's constrained based on the passed `T`.

Example:

```js
const foo = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'world',
} as const

function bar<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key1: K, key2: K) {};

bar(foo, 'a', 'b') // No error, even though key1 should narrow K to 'a'. K stays 'a'|'b'
```

My goal is ultimately to pass an object, constrain other paramaters based on its type, and infer their values when they're passed to constrain other parameters further:

- Passed parameter infers `T` & constrains `K`
- Passed second parameter infers `K` & constrains `V`
- etc.

Comment: "even though key1 should narrow K to 'a'" why should it? You could call that function with any two keys of foo in any order. "Passed second parameter infers K & constrains V" what V? Please edit your question to clearly indicate what you're after here.

Comment: I want it to work in the same way `T` narrows `K`. `V` is just extrapolating the example, they're all placeholders. You can imagine `K` as a union of objects and the passed argument narrowing it to one of the objects, then `V` being they keys of the narrowed object. The specific union of `K` depends on the value of `T`.

Comment: Essentially, passing a parameter should infer the type of the generic as long as it respects the constraint.

Comment: "T narrows K" it doesn't: you have *constrained* `K` to the keys of `T`. "imagine K as a union of objects" why/how? In your code K is a union of string literal types. I still don't understand where you're getting "V" from or how I'm supposed to treat it.

Comment: "Essentially, passing a parameter should infer the type of the generic as long as it respects the constraint" what if it's a dynamic value instead of a statically known compile-time constant? There's no way to say "this function only takes static compile-time constants". If that's what you want use an enum which is arguably the closest thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tradeoff when multiple inference candidates exist for a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)
type argument. If you have a function like

```
declare function f<T>(x: T, y: T): void;
```

and someone calls

```
declare const a: A;
declare const b: B;
f(a, b); // <-- ?
```

what should happen?  On one extreme, the compiler could reject any call where `A` and `B` are not identical types.  On the other extreme, it could accept anything by synthesizing the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `A | B`.  There are use cases for either behavior and for something in between, and different people want different things at different times.

So currently TypeScript just uses heuristic rules which have been found to work well over a large range of real-world scenarios, but which sometimes disappoints people.

---

The heuristics are mostly that union types will not be synthesized unless the multiple candidates are part of the same primitive type.  So if instead of `"a"` and `"b"` (both strings) you used `"a"` and `3` (a string and a number), you'd get the error you expected:

```
const foo = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'world',
  3: 'abc'
} as const

function bar<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T, key1: K, key2: K) { };

bar(foo, 'a', 3) // error
// ---------> ~  3 is not assignable to 'a'
```

But when both types are [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) that would widen to the same primitive type, like `"a"` and `"b"` are both subtypes of `string`, TypeScript *does* synthesize union types to allow it to succeed, as you've seen.

This is not what you happen to want, but again, these are heuristics that work well in many other cases.

---

So, is there a way to tell the compiler you want something else?  In this case you'd like to say "`key2` should only be *checked* against the type `K` inferred from `key1`.  It should *not* be used to infer `K` itself".  That is, `key2` should be a "non-inferential type parameter usage", such as a hypothetical `NoInfer<T>` utility type requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829):

```
function bar<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T, key1: K, key2: NoInfer<K>) { };

bar(foo, 'a', 'b') // error
// ---------> ~~~ 'b' not assignable to 'a'
```

That's an open issue, so right now there's no *native* implementation of `NoInfer<T>`.  Luckily there are various approaches discussed within that you can use to define it yourself, which work for some use cases (but nothing seems to work everywhere).  One way [described here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) is:

```
type NoInfer<T> = T & {}
```

which assigns `NoInfer<T>` a lower inference priority compared to `T`, and so the compiler will tend to infer from `T` and not from `NoInfer<T>`.  If you write it that way you get the behavior you want.

Another approach is to just declare another type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the first one.  It will block inference also:

```
function bar<T extends object, K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends K1>(
  obj: T, key1: K1, key2: K2
) { };

bar(foo, 'a', 'b') // error
```

Either way should work, at least for the example code in the question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgPICcCWBzNAb1FDTWQHsw4AXNAMworQF4jSy0IAuNAcgAWMADbCKfADQcyAI158A7hSzCAJpOloAzPIgzkfDgF8ucclVokQZegFcwyGjipoZELAB4AKmhgAPGhgwVTMKGQArGEcJNABpXwCgkLQAaxgATwp6NC8APgAKTTDw3i8YtPSARl5Y8oyAJhqASiI0IwBuK1l3fMYKGL4ISW0WgHpR3ywsZSsjK0hYRBR0ADkKAEkwehgsdmtzajo+1j3OLnkhUXEpfdl5JRV1G7Odfj0DY1MDyxAOGnSEKsNlsdt5cicfAAyIhzfZ2BxOFxuTw+fyBYKhCJRGgxeJopJmCpZHIFIoRUp1Ko1SmNNBrTbbTyxXItQhtTq-fbI3pMAZDAYyPhjCY7aZYUCw0ALeBIVBoACiASwEAA4kEdjhkKdvkcmCdiLdzvxLmINIa5PwHmozWQTBAzJRDl0GPZHM4wK53N4EujksVsbjKj6CakMsSynF6sGMXFKqTDcUKaGqbGaTV6hxWezndy+nzhnxBcLJmLZkA)

Comment: How on Earth did you get that (assuming it actually addresses OP's concerns) out of that question? Real talk, I definitely can see how that could possibly answer the question but the question itself still reads as pretty vague to me (although my back-and-forth with the OP in the comments has been productive). What clued you in to what OP wanted (for me to do better next time)?

Comment: Uhhh I think the comment `No error, even though key1 should narrow K to 'a'. K stays 'a'|'b` and reinterpreting "narrow" to mean something like "constrain"  (and mostly ignoring the `V` stuff at the bottom)

Comment: Yeah, I may have gotten distracted by that part, I still have no idea what OP meant other than possibly the earlier parameters constraining the later ones, in the OP's code you could pass the same key of foo twice and I thought maybe they were trying to get at some compile-time way of preventing that but I never got enough clarity to feel comfortable rolling with that.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Didn't consider a the concept of stopping inference for the parameter. The last approach is also really clever too.